# Visual Studio Code Debugger not launching

Tags: visual-studio-code

- OS and Version: Windows 10 Build 19042.985
- VS Code Version: 1.56.2
- C/C++ Extension Version: v1.4.0-insiders
- other extensions: remote-ssh

I've been working with remote-ssh on a raspberry and c/c++ extension without any issue, all of a sudden I cannot start the debugger. Nothing changed, configuration files are the same as before but now when I start the debugger, I see for a couple of seconds the top debugging bar and then it disappears. No message on the console, nothing.

For this purpose, I created a simple project from scratch, and even there, the same issue appears.

**To Reproduce**
launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true },
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("ciao\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Compile with `gcc -g main.c`

As I stated before, this workflow worked for me, from one second to another it stopped working as intended and I have no idea why and how to fix it, any help is appreciated.

### What I tried

- reinstall vscode
- reinstall the c/c++ extension and delete by hand the extension folder
- numerous reboots

### Updates

I have tried with the wsl-remote extension and it is working as expected.ù

Tried to uninstall gdb from host and launch the debug session, the message "gdb" not found does not even appear as it should

Comment: Is it possible that the (test) program simply regularly exits? Try setting `"stopAtEntry": true,`

Comment: @Omni nope, I've put breakpoints but nothing, this misbehavior happens before even starting gdb, in fact I have uninstalled and I have the same behavior

Comment: Hello! It seems I have a similar issue. Debug panel shows for a second and then disappears without launching debugger. Did you find the cause of the problem?

Comment: @DAle hello, at the end I solved by reinstalling the entire OS on the target machine, I was desperate. I think it is some ssh configuration on the target that was messing up with the remote debug

Comment: Not sure if this is your specific problem, but or me the latest python debugger had an issues. I could go into the python extension and on the uninstall drop down select previous version to go back to the previous debugger.

Answer (score 4):

I was in similar situation and couldn't find relevant resolutions:

**Quick Answer:**
After upgrade to VS Code 1.56.2, make sure to remove old breakpoints and create new breakpoint and at-least have 1 breakpoint and launch.json available.

**Lengthy details:**

I have similar issue for python scripts when I start the "debugger bar" I see it for a couple of seconds the top debugging bar and then it disappears. Bu then no message on the console, nothing. I tried reinstalling VS Code, enabling/disabling extension, various restart.

- OS and Version: Mac OSX Version 11.4 (20F71)
- VS Code Version: 1.56.2
- Extension: Python v2021.5.842923320 by Microsoft

**RootCause:**

What I did know for sure that I updated my VS Code, and after that this mysterious issue start happening, so when to release log of VS Code 1.56.2. I found below release log

> Debug view displayed on break#
>
> The default value of the debug.openDebug setting is now
> openOnDebugBreak so that on every breakpoint hit, VS Code will open
> the Debug view. The Debug view is also displayed on first session
> start.

So VS code Version 1.56 release, debugger will only show when at-least 1 breakpoint is found. However, looks like there is issue with their internal code checking for historical breakpoint data after VS Code upgrade..

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_debug-view-displayed-on-break

Comment: Thank you! To add from my experience: After removing the breakpoints as suggested, needed to close all other vs code windows and quit the app (on macos)  - and only then would it start working again 

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue in python. The fix for python was changing to a valid interpreter due to a python library not being installed. Make sure that the interpreter is correct and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a faulty installation of the VS Code C/C++ extension. When launching VS Code, if the message "*Unable to start the C/C++ language server. IntelliSense features will be disabled*" appears, this is probably the cause. Was able to fix the installation in this case by installing a previous version of the C/C++ extension as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1600657/unable-to-start-the-c-c-language-server-intellisense-features-will-be-disable).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (though the debug bar would show up for a second and then disappear). I was using a conda env with python 3.6. I updated to 3.8, with the same dependencies, and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem when I was debugging C++ in a container. I created the launch.json file in the container, which created it on the host machine as root (because the source code was mounted into the container from the host and I was root in the container). I then started another container and the debugger wouldn't launch. I realized the owner of launch.json was root, so on a haunch I changed the owner from the host machine to my usual user, restarted vs code, and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

For me this did the trick:

1. Open the Command Palette in Visual Studio Code by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P.
2. Type Python: Select Interpreter and press Enter.
3. A list of available Python interpreters will be displayed. These include virtual environments, conda environments, and system-wide Python installations. Select the interpreter you wish to use from the list.